java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mojaduodeejays.servlets while deploying war file
{
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {
        "jboss.deployment.unit."mojaduodeejays-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war".undertow-deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService" => 
            "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mojaduodeejays.servlets 
                from [Module "deployment.mojaduodeejays-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" 
                    from Service Module Loader] 
            Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mojaduodeejays.servlets 
                from [Module "deployment.mojaduodeejays-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" 
                    from Service Module Loader]"
    }
} 

I was trying to deploy my war file on wildfly but it keeps giving me this error

Do you have a web.xml file with a servlet named com.mojaduodeejays.servlets defined?
